# Update HTML content after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `HTML` div that contains 3 rooms. What I need is to change the name of any room when I want. "EDIT ROOM NAME" button makes 'contenteditable="false"'. After I type the desired name, I press the "VALIDATE NAME" button but as you can see, the alert message displays the previous name, not the new one. Only when I click on the room name again the "nameTag" variable refreshes and takes the new value. My question is how do I get the value after I finished typing the desired name?

Below is the demo:

```js
$("#editButton").click(function (){
      var idTag;
      var nameTag;
      alert("DoubleClick the room you want to rename")
      $(".roomClass").click(function (){
          $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
          idTag = $(this).attr("data-room-id");
          nameTag = $(this).text();
      })
      $("#confirmButton").click(function () {
          PostData(idTag, nameTag);
      })
  })


function PostData(idTag, nameTag) {
        alert(nameTag + ' with id: ' + idTag + ' was renamed!');
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="vertical-menu">
        <h3>ROOM LIST:</h3>
<button id="editButton">EDIT ROOM NAME</button><br>
        <a id="content11" class="roomClass" contenteditable="false" data-room-id="0" style="cursor: pointer;">ROOM1</a><br>
        <a id="content10" class="roomClass" contenteditable="false" data-room-id="9" style="cursor: pointer;">ROOM2</a><br>
        <a id="content9" class="roomClass" contenteditable="false" data-room-id="8" style="cursor: pointer;">ROOM3</a><br>
        <br><br>
        
        <button id="confirmButton">VALIDATE NAME</button> 
        
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below js code..

```js
 $("#editButton").click(function (){
      var idTag;
      var nameTag;
      var roomId;
      alert("DoubleClick the room you want to rename")
      $(".roomClass").click(function (){
          $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
          idTag = $(this).attr("data-room-id");
          roomId = $(this).attr("id");
      });
      $("#confirmButton").click(function () {
       nameTag = $('#'+roomId).text();
          PostData(idTag, nameTag);
      });
  })


function PostData(idTag, nameTag) {
        alert(nameTag + ' with id: ' + idTag + ' was renamed!');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

you can get value simply by using `.text()` jquery function
like :

```
var room8Value = $("[data-room-id=8]").text();
```

you can check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anaselalami/xpvt214o/766551/) example

```js
$("#editButton").click(function (){
    var idTag;
    var nameTag;
    alert("DoubleClick the room you want to rename")
    $(".roomClass").click(function (){
        $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
        idTag = $(this).attr("data-room-id");
        nameTag = $(this).text();
    })
    $("#confirmButton").click(function () {
        PostData(idTag, nameTag);
    })
});


function PostData(idTag, nameTag) {
        alert(nameTag + ' with id: ' + idTag + ' was renamed! to :' + $("[data-room-id="+idTag+"]").text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="vertical-menu">
        <h3>ROOM LIST:</h3>
<button id="editButton">EDIT ROOM NAME</button><br>
        <a id="content11" class="roomClass" contenteditable="false" data-room-id="0" style="cursor: pointer;">ROOM1</a><br>
        <a id="content10" class="roomClass" contenteditable="false" data-room-id="9" style="cursor: pointer;">ROOM2</a><br>
        <a id="content9" class="roomClass" contenteditable="false" data-room-id="8" style="cursor: pointer;">ROOM3</a><br>
        <br><br>
        
        <button id="confirmButton">VALIDATE NAME</button> 
        
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've already done that. The problem is this method doesn't get the new value (the one I typed). I need to click again on the room in order to get the value, check the demo

Comment: what you need is when you update one of those rooms name, and click "validate name" you get the new values ?

Comment: that's exactly what I need!

Comment: did you check my jsfiddle example ?

Comment: the "nameTag " parameter in PostData function should contain the data that is shown in " $("[data-room-id="+idTag+"]").text())". Thank you for your time, I have found the answer

Answer (score 2):

Use  `var idTag;` and `var nameTag;` as public variable, you had applied this variable inside `$("#editButton").click()` apply them outside

Please check below:

```js
var idTag;
var nameTag;

$("#editButton").click(function (){
    alert("DoubleClick the room you want to rename")
 $(".roomClass").click(function (){
     $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
  idTag = $(this).attr("data-room-id");
  nameTag = $(this).text();
    })
 
    $("#confirmButton").click(function () {
     PostData(idTag, nameTag);
 })
})

function PostData(idTag, nameTag) {
    alert(nameTag + ' with id: ' + idTag + ' was renamed!');
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="vertical-menu">
        <h3>ROOM LIST:</h3>
        <button id="editButton">EDIT ROOM NAME</button><br>
        <a id="content11" class="roomClass" contenteditable="false" data-room-id="0" style="cursor: pointer;">ROOM1</a><br>
        <a id="content10" class="roomClass" contenteditable="false" data-room-id="9" style="cursor: pointer;">ROOM2</a><br>
        <a id="content9" class="roomClass" contenteditable="false" data-room-id="8" style="cursor: pointer;">ROOM3</a><br>
        <br><br>
        
        <button id="confirmButton">VALIDATE NAME</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```